# SQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE `comment` 

SET `agree`=`agree`+1,(INSERT INTO `reacted_on` VALUES (10,197))
WHERE `id`=197 and 0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reacted_on` WHERE `id_user`=10 and `id_comment`=197)

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'(INSERT INTO `reacted_on` VALUES (10,197)) WHERE `id`=197 and 0 = (SELECT COUNT(' at line 1
```

I want to icrement `agree` in `comment` but i want to prevent same user to agree on a comment more than one. Therefore, first I check if user reacted on the same comment; I increment agree. Then I insert a row to prevent user from reacting on the same comment anymore.

What am I missing? why is it not true?
What should I do to fix the problem?

How can I use INSERT statement in UPDATE query?

This is where I use the query:

```
        $con = mysql_connect($my_sql_servername,$my_sql_username,$my_sql_password);
        mysql_select_db($my_sql_database, $con);
        if($validation != $_SESSION['validation'])
            die('-1');
        $sql = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `reacted_on` WHERE `id_user`=".$id_user." and `id_comment`=".$id_comment."  ) THEN INSERT INTO `reacted_on` VALUES (10,197); UPDATE `comment` SET `agree`=`agree`+1 WHERE `id`=".$id_comment." END IF;";
        //echo $sql;
        if(!mysql_query($sql)){die(mysql_error());}
```

Comment: strange query????? Update and insert TOGETHER???

Comment: I need to use them both so How can I use them in one query?

Comment: comment(id cmt odate agree disagree validation)

Comment: reacted_on(id_user,id_comment)

Comment: please provide STRUCTURE OF BOTH tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, something like this, probably:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT *
              FROM `reacted_on`
              WHERE `id_user`=10 and `id_comment`=197
              )
THEN
  INSERT INTO `reacted_on` VALUES (10,197);
  UPDATE `comment`
  SET `agree`=`agree`+1
  WHERE `id`=197;
END IF;
```

You'll have to do that using separate statements, but you can wrap them into a single `IF` instruction.

---

**EDIT**

Another way to check for the existence of rows is to use `SELECT COUNT(*)...` (just like you did in your attempted script). So the beginning of the above query would change to:

```
IF 0 = (
       SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM `reacted_on`
       WHERE `id_user`=10 and `id_comment`=197
       )
THEN
  ... /* same as above */
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (
                                      SELECT *
                                      FROM `reacted_on`
                                      WHER' at line 1

Comment: @exculuber: Well, I give up, I can't see the error. Could it possibly be something *before* `IF`? A statement not closed with `;` so there's an attempt to treat `IF` as a function?  *Update:* No, I don't think so, as it says 'at line 1'... Then maybe it's because of `WHER` which should be `WHERE`?

Comment: I copied the codes from the php page and put them under my question, but nothing seems wrong

Comment: @exculuber: Indeed, everything seems fine. The `$sql` is sure to be able to hold all the query, is it? (Sorry if it's a dumb question.) I hope, someone more experienced in MySQL than I, can spot the mistake. Meanwhile I'm adding another way to check for the existence of the row, though both ways are perfectly trivial and a mistake *should* be obvious, if indeed present.

Comment: thank you for answers you are the only person who give answers as I wanted, but it doesn't work still. SQL: `IF 0=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reacted_on WHERE id_user=1 and id_comment=197  ) THEN INSERT INTO reacted_on VALUES (10,197); UPDATE comment SET agree=agree+1 WHERE id=197 END IF;` but still doesnt work

Comment: @exculuber: That's a shame really. Could you verify the script itself in MySQL at least? Because I would have certainly did that if I'd had MySQL at hand. It's the primary question so far, whether the script is all right.

Comment: I tried on phpmyadmin and got this message `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF 0=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reacted_on WHERE id_user=1 and id_comment=197 ) THEN ' at line 1 `

Comment: @exculuber: Well, it seems like I was a bit too hasty then to say 'I give up', because it's only now that I've really given up. :) Sorry, I would really like to find the answer to this problem myself.

Comment: @exculuber: Um, actually no, here's one last thing I've just discovered: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,386985,387167#msg-387167. Possibly the guy has got a different problem, but the reason for it may be the same. At least I would try to follow the other guy's advice (to use the MySQL client).

Answer (score 2):

It's just plain wrong ;)

You're doing an `UPDATE` query and then, out of nowhere, there's an `INSERT` subquery where you can't have on. I'll even say there is a closing parenthesis which have nothing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do here? Describe it in terms of the business logic of your application.

It looks like you might be trying to insert a row in table `reacted_on`, and then update the corresponding row in table `comment`. The best way to do this is to issue two queries, one after the other. Better still, wrap the two queries in a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html); that way if anything goes wrong, your tables will not be left inconsistent.

Comment: I want to icrement `agree` in comment but i want to prevent same user to agree on a comment more than one. Therefore, first I check if user reacted on the same comment ; I increment agree, then I insert a row to prevent user from reacting on the same comment anymore.

Comment: Then you had best use three statements. The first one is a SELECT query and checks whether the row already exists; the second one is an INSERT query; and the third one is an UPDATE. For best results, wrap all of them in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

> if u insert

```
  INSERT INTO `reacted_on` (id_user,id_comment) VALUES (10,197); ( first correct your insert statement) 
  then
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reacted_on` WHERE `id_user`=10 and `id_comment`=197`
```

> will always returns greater than 1

please explain what exactly u want to do??
u can not update two table together in mysql (AFAIK)

#### update

i dont know what is your relation between two tables but i suggest below way

```
$count_comment = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `reacted_on` WHERE `id_user`=10 and `id_comment`=197"); 
if(!$count_comment)
{
    $sql= " UPDATE `comment` SET `agree`=`agree`+1 WHERE `id`=197";
    mysql_query($sql);
    $sql2= " INSERT INTO `reacted_on`(id_user,id_comment) VALUES (10,197) ";
    mysql_query($sql2);     
}
else
{ 
    // whatever u want to display
}
```

Comment: @exculuber i update my answer as well as your question too, see n check

Comment: Sure, there are many ways to do it. However, I want to make this in one SQL query.